# Formating cells in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

even after years of occasional work in Excel I didn't find a way how to make cell formats work for me, instead against. Now I have one specific example. How to make 1:30 to mean 90 minutes instead of 1:30AM? I have column of times using which I need to sort, so I can't use general (which turns my time into decimal number anyway) or text.

Edit:

From my experience, data in cells ARE changed by Excel. Here is the example 1:

I put into an unformatted cell this value:

25:42:00

It immediately gets changed to 1/1/1900  1:42:00 AM which is absurd, I entered something completely else. If I try to change the cell format to text, I get 1.07083333333333. By now I don't even know original value I entered or how to get back to it.

Example 2:

Let's have input like:

113:23

5:22

18:53

28:07

14:36

18:02

20:32

47:40

7:39

9:04

All I want is to have this sorted from shortest to longest duration. After entering this list into Excel some of the values are changed to time of the day, others to date+time. If I change the cell format to let's say h:mm, I'm loosing data already, 113:23 is now 17:23 as it converts to '1/4/1900  5:23:00 PM'.

How can I say Excel WHAT format I entered data in? It's effectively the opposite of the 'cell format', which expects Excel knows what data are in the cell and I can format its display. But Excel often doesn't know it right, like now, so it can't interpret it properly. How do I tell it: this is duration, not time of the day.

Comment: [Converting Time into Minutes using Excel](https://www.proworkflow.com/blog/2009/02/converting-time-into-minutes-using-excel/)

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks but that's not what I'm asking. Yes, I could multiply cell with 1440 but with values like 170:45 you get just long, unintuitive number. I just need the value means length, not time of a day.

Comment: That's all very well, but you need minutes to do the sorting correctly ... when you convert to minutes it is effectively a length (measured in minutes) and is no longer a time of day. Asking what time if day is 90 minutes is a meaningless question.

Comment: What I suspect you need to do (and I'm no excel guru so I don't know if this is even possible) is to have a hidden column (containing the number of minutes) and somehow use the hidden column to drive the sorting of the visible column.

Comment: Bear in mind that the cell formats only changes the way the number is shown, not the actual number stored in the cell. Changing formats will not change the actual number. If you need different values than the ones shown to do something (like, sorting), then you must create a new column to store the new numbers.

Comment: Why can't you sort using the formatted times?  Times are stored in Excel as fractions of a day -- so they will sort numerically, no matter the format and no matter what  you multiply by.  Please describe your sorting issue in more detail, preferably by editing your post to show your current data, what you expect for results, and what you are getting now for results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for adding the example.

There should be no problem sorting that list from shortest to longest, as shown in my screen shot below.

But you need to understand how Excel stores dates and times.  Excel stores days as integers, with 1 = 1 Jan 1900, and the times as fractions of a day.

This decimal value is displayed in the worksheet cell depending on the format of that cell; and it is displayed in the formula bar, as you already see, in the `m/d/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM` format.

The format in the formula bar cannot be changed, but is irrelevant to sorting.

The value stored, for your first entry of `113:23`, is `4.72430555555556`.
The value displayed in the formula bar will be
`1/4/1900  5:23:00 PM`

and the value displayed in the cell will be `113:23:00` with a format of `[h]:mm:ss`.  Excel chose that format because it noted you had entered a time with more than 24 hours.

In the screenshot below, I first opened a new Excel sheet in a new Excel workbook, with no special formatting (e.g. formatted as `General`).

Column A is your original column of numbers from your edit.

Column C is a copy of column A, but sorted ascending -- note that they are in the proper order.

Column E shows column C with all of the cells formatted as `[h]:mm`

Column G shows the underlying value stored in the cells in Column E

Hopefully my explanation is clear, but feel free to ask any questions.

[image]

Comment: Aha! You're the man, thank you, Ron. The whole trick why I couldn't make it work, is the magic in column E of your example. What does those square brackets around hours mean? They do exactly the thing I was looking for. It all basically means I shouldn't care HOW Excels stores times, because I cannot change it, I just need to make it display right, is that correct?

Comment: @Ren `[h]` displays time in hours.  `h` displays the hour of the day. So if you need to display more than 23 hours, you use the `[h]` format.

Comment: @Ren Knowledge of how Excel stores times is important, although perhaps not relevant to this particular problem.  But, for example, if you want to compute total salary or costs from elapsed time, you would need that information to perform the computation correctly.